# Registre du mot « véracité »

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, synonymes, registre

Je me demande quel est le registre du mot 'véracité'. Est-ce un terme couramment employé ? Dans quel contexte et registre peut-on l'utiliser ?

Comment: En logique mathématique, on parle souvent de la véracité d'une formule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On dit 'véracité' plutot que 'vérité' quand on parle de la qualité d'un concept, plutot que du concept lui meme.

> Je sais que la terre est ronde, c'est la vérité.
>
> Galilée a démontré la véracité de ce fait.

C'est du francais plutot formel, mais tout à fait courant.

Answer (score 1):

C'est un mot de la langue recherchée ;

> (TLFi) 2. a) Caractère de ce qui est conforme à la vérité, à la réalité. Synon. authenticité, exactitude
>
> (Larousse)
>  
>   - Littéraire. Habitude de dire le vrai.
>   - Qualité de ce qui est vrai, conforme à la vérité : La 
>   véracité d'un témoignage.

Le mot « vérité » est définie comme suit ;

> (TLFi) Connaissance reconnue comme juste, comme conforme à son objet et possédant à ce titre une valeur absolue, ultime.

Si au lieu de « véracité » on utilisait « vérité » on aurait une ambiguïté ;

- cela pourrait signifier  que le principe de la thermodynamique est une vérité et qu'elle n'est pas démontrable ;
- cela pourrait aussi signifier qu'il n'y a pas de démonstration pour dire si le principe est vrai ou non.

Les deux assertions reviennent à peu près à la même chose, seulement celle construite avec le mot « vérité » n'est pas plaisante parce que, pour ainsi dire, elle ne comporte rien qui nous dise par quel bout la prendre et donc avant de savoir trop bien ce qui est dit il faut penser aux deux possibilités et conclure que cela revient à la même chose ; le bon usager du langage évite ces sortes de contextes linguistiques, comme il est préférable de dire les chose aussi rapidement et nettement que possible.

Cela se voit à partir de la définition suivante ;

> (Larousse) Caractère de ce qui existe réellement et est bien tel qu'il apparaît : 
>   On ne saurait douter de la vérité de ses sentiments.

« Véracité » peut donc, dans un certain contexte être synonyme de « vérité », dont voici une liste de synonymes ;

> quelques synonymes : exactitude, authenticité, justesse, réalité, véracité, véridicité

Utiliser ce terme, donc, élimine l'ambiguïté ; on aurait pu utiliser aussi le terme « véridicité » ((TLFi)  b) Caractère de ce qui est conforme à la vérité) mais « véracité » est plus courant.

Answer (score 1):

La véracité d'un item, d'une proposition ou d'une idée, c'est sa Vérité majuscule.
La vérité est falsifiable, elle s'oppose au Faux.
La véracité possède la dureté du granit: elle a prouvé sa vérité dans la durée, dans le temps; comme telle, elle s'oppose à l'inconstance, à l'improvisation, à la légèreté, tout autant qu'à la fausseté.
Véracité des témoignages, lors du Procès de Socrate.

Answer (score 0):

> La notion de vérité s'applique proprement à des énoncés. La notion de
> véracité s'applique à des personnes. La véracité est le propre de
> celui qui n'est pas trompeur, qui répugne au mensonge, à la tromperie.
> La véracité est le caractère moral de celui qui a l'intention de dire
> la vérité. Source : https://www.philolog.fr/verite-veracite/

Comment: Dans la langue courante en tout cas, on ne parle pas de la véracité d'une personne (jamais entendu en 40 ans).